# Super Macro For each item where H is not and U is null

Tags: excel, vba

[Example data](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6qTKfuEA6y6ZkxLdTdvX293aHN6VnAxNTNuSjkybGRWX3E4/edit?usp=docslist_api&filetype=msexcel)
I am trying to come up with a macro that will populate the "Pass On" tab with the corresponding data in the "Data" tab for each item that does not have "QC-Completed" in column H or a container in column U.

I have not even come close yet.

Comment: what's wrong with your pivot table, filter or advanced filter command?

Comment: This piece is going to fit in to a more complex macro that I have already built. The goal is to produce the report I do now with a single button so that I can push it off onto the end users (who wouldn't even know what a pivot table was) and eliminate myself from the process.

Comment: I might be over complicating it. Can you set a range based on a variable? If I could set my range as lines where "U" is null then I can reduce it to a single variable.

Comment: Thank you Qharr. I have added my current code which I don't know will be particularly helpful since I don't have anything regarding this part in there yet. I am trying to find a way to post my data but I am restricted at work.

Comment: I got the data file added via my google drive.

Comment: Probably worth having a read of [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which details how to write a question that helps us target your specific problem.

Comment: Thank you again QHarr. I have attempted to modify it so that it fits within that directive.

Comment: Your attempt before was closer to be honest. But you are responding. What I had meant was post enough code that demonstrates your efforts to filter, copy and paste. @Jeeped mentioned filtering and I have posted an answer along the same lines that does an all in one copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

### **Process:**

**A) Define the filter range**

I define the range to work with by finding the last used row and column, based on row 1 and column A, and store this in the `filterRange` variable.

**B) Clear any existing filter**

I make sure there is no existing filter:

```
wsSource.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Notice that I have put the source and target sheets into worksheet variables for ease of reference?

**C) Apply filter criteria**

I then work with that range to apply the two criteria:

```
With filterRange

        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=filterField1, Criteria1:="<>" criterion1, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .AutoFilter Field:=filterField2, Criteria1:=criterion2
```

Notice here that I have used constants to hold the columns of interest, and the filter criteria to work with e.g. `filterField1` and `criterion1`. This means you can easily adjust these at the top of your code if you decide to change how you are applying filters. Obviously still limited to two columns but easy to see how you would extend this.

**D) Extract the columns of interest and order them**

Now, as we don't want all the filtered data we are going to need to do 3 things:

1) Get all the filtered data

So, the following makes use of the  `.AutoFilter.Range` object, to get the filtered range, and then uses a Resize to exclude the header row. We already have a header in the other sheet. This is dumped into an array, which as it is read in from the sheet is Option Base 1, not 0. 0 is the normal lower bound for an array.

```
With wsSource.AutoFilter.Range

    dataArray = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count) 'exclude header

End With
```

2) Reduce this to the columns of interest

3) Have those columns in the specified order `S,AD,B,C,E,H,L`

2 & 3 are achieved by using an array specifying the columns to keep, in the desired order.

```
 Dim columnsToKeep() As Variant
 columnsToKeep = Array(19, 30, 2, 3, 5, 8, 12)
```

You then create an array to hold the results you want to write out to the sheet, `resultArray`, which you know will have the same number of rows as the array you already have, `dataArray`, and will have the same number of columns as items in the `columnsToKeep` array i.e. `UBound(columnsToKeep) + 1`. Notice the + 1 as that array uses the default base 0 option.

We loop the rows of the `dataArray` and then, inside this loop, we loop the columns specified by `columnsToKeep`. This means we can use `columnsToKeep(currentColumn)` to return the value, from the specified column, in the source array, `dataArray`, in the order presented in `columnsToKeep`. To make sure this is loaded into the `resultArray`, with a column numbering going from 1 onwards, an additional `columnCounter` variable is used to specify the output column.

```
For currentRow = LBound(dataArray, 1) To UBound(dataArray, 1)

        columnCounter = 0

        For currentColumn = LBound(columnsToKeep) To UBound(columnsToKeep)

            columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
            resultArray(currentRow, columnCounter) = dataArray(currentRow, columnsToKeep(currentColumn))

        Next currentColumn

    Next currentRow
```

**E) Write results out to second sheet**

Finally, we write everything out to the other sheet below the header:

```
  wsTarget.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(resultArray, 1), UBound(resultArray, 2)) = resultArray
```

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyData()

    'Range("H1").Select
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Const filterField1 As Long = 8               'Column H
    Const filterField2 As Long = 21              'Column U
    Const criterion1 As String = "QC-Completed"
    Const criterion2 As String = vbNullString

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Data")
    Set wsTarget = wb.Worksheets("Pass On")

    Dim lastRowSource As Long
    lastRowSource = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim lastColumnSource As Long
    lastColumnSource = wsSource.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

    Dim filterRange As Range
    Set filterRange = wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(1, 1), wsSource.Cells(lastRowSource, lastColumnSource))

    wsSource.AutoFilterMode = False
    Dim dataArray As Variant

    With filterRange

        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=filterField1, criteria1:="<>" & criteria1, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .AutoFilter Field:=filterField2, criteria1:=criteria2

        With wsSource.AutoFilter.Range

             dataArray = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count) 'exclude header

        End With

    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False              'Clear clipboard

    Dim columnsToKeep() As Variant
    columnsToKeep = Array(19, 30, 2, 3, 5, 8, 12) 'determine output columns to keep and their orser

    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim currentColumn As Long
    Dim resultArray() As Variant
    ReDim resultArray(1 To UBound(dataArray, 1), 1 To UBound(columnsToKeep) + 1)
    Dim columnCounter As Long

    For currentRow = LBound(dataArray, 1) To UBound(dataArray, 1)

        columnCounter = 0

        For currentColumn = LBound(columnsToKeep) To UBound(columnsToKeep)

            columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
            resultArray(currentRow, columnCounter) = dataArray(currentRow, columnsToKeep(currentColumn))

        Next currentColumn

    Next currentRow

    wsTarget.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(resultArray, 1), UBound(resultArray, 2)) = resultArray

End Sub
```

References:

1. [A Better Way to Copy Filtered Rows Using VBA](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/a-better-way-to-copy-filtered-rows-using-vba/)
2. [AutoFilter macro for "does not contain"](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/271528-autofilter-macro-does-not-contain.html)
3. [Find last row, column or last cell](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm)